# Spring Security Redirects to login page and kills sessions after authentication success

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4.2.1 to authenticate a SpringMVC webapp. I have a very elusive issue that seems to work sometimes and be broken others (is broken more than it works).

The issue is as follows:

- Upon login attempt, the AuthenticationProvider properly authenticates the user and I see Authentication Success in the logs (and the Authenticated user has all the Authorities needed, etc, I can see them in the logs).
- The framework then seems to clear the SecurityContextHolder for the user, and when it attempts to load the landing page, its as if they are not authenticated at all
- This of course results in a redirect back to the login page.
- The EXCEPTION is if I logout explicitly first. If I go to the logout address, I seem to be able to login after that.

I have reviewed my Spring Sec config and changed things in it for days and still get the same result. I am losing my mind over it.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/link/go/*",
                "/pixel/download/*",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/ping*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .authenticationDetailsSource(new CustomAuthenticationDetailsSource())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

This is a basic Controller that has this behaviour:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showIndex() {
    return "pages/index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    return "pages/login";
}
```

This is the basic login form which I am using (Thymeleaf):

```
<form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="group">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="off" required="required" /><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Username</label>
        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">    
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success"> 
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" required="required" /><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="text" id="token" name="token" autocomplete="off" required="required" /><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Tracker Token</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="button buttonBlue">Log in
        <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
    </button>
</form>
```

These are very relevant logs (The cycle of succesful authentication followed by session destruction and Access Denial). I logged heavy for context but I'm pointing out the key parts (with *) so that you don't have to dig too hard.

```
2017-01-24 10:32:25,386 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,386 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,386 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT

*2017-01-24 10:32:25,386 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1ff52ee9. A new one will be created.

2017-01-24 10:32:25,386 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,386 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter: Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@362f8994
2017-01-24 10:32:25,386 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,387 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: /j_spring_security_check at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,387 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/logout'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,387 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy: /j_spring_security_check at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'

*2017-01-24 10:32:25,387 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,387 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter: Request is to process authentication
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,388 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager: Authentication attempt using com.company.project.tracker.config.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider

2017-01-24 10:32:25,729 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,729 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy: Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@473f5bae
2017-01-24 10:32:25,729 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,729 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy: Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy@213137f3

*2017-01-24 10:32:25,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter: Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7d972f2: Principal: com.company.project.tracker.config.security.Principal@50525059; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: com.company.project.tracker.config.security.CustomAuthenticationDetailsSource$CustomAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: BFDA41C5C1883560BACC75BB353001CA; Granted Authorities: com.company.project.tracker.config.security.UserAuthority@78746e0b

2017-01-24 10:32:25,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'

*2017-01-24 10:32:25,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler: Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: http://localhost:8080/tracker
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy: Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/tracker'
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d7d972f2: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d7d972f2: Principal: com.company.project.tracker.config.security.Principal@50525059; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: com.company.project.tracker.config.security.CustomAuthenticationDetailsSource$CustomAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: BFDA41C5C1883560BACC75BB353001CA; Granted Authorities: com.company.project.tracker.config.security.UserAuthority@78746e0b' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1ff52ee9
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,730 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I Think this is the cutoff where it starts to process the authenticated request (i.e. where it all goes wrong).

```
2017-01-24 10:32:25,733 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'

*2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: No HttpSession currently exists
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.

2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter: Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@362f8994
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Request 'GET ' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Request 'GET ' doesn't match 'POST /j_spring_security_check
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'

*2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter: Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:  at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Request 'GET ' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : ''; against '/link/go/*'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : ''; against '/pixel/download/*'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : ''; against '/favicon.ico'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Checking match of request : ''; against '/ping*'
2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor: Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: ; Attributes: [authenticated]

*2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor: Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased: Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2cca1b0b, returned: -1
*2017-01-24 10:32:25,734 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter: Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

So as you can see, when it gets back to the '/' address, the session is gone, and the original, correct object which was stored in the session is replaced by an anonymous authentication object, which obviously is not authorized to go to '/'. I have also included the corresponding response and request headers (via chrome) which is from the same request cycle as the logs above:

[All Three Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw7FO.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am certain I am doing something stupid. I have used this framework for years and even written a ton of custom components but this one has me thoroughly stumped (1d+ of experimenting). I can provide any other files or samples if they help get to the bottom of it.

Thanks.

Comment: After further analysis I can see in the very link I posted that chrome is not sending back the JSESSIONID in the 302. I'm starting to think this is not Spring Security's fault, but I am still stuck as to why. There is an explicity set-cookie on the POST response from the auth method, so to not set the cookie in the / request just seems crazy.

Answer (score 0):

TRy to add http.csrf().disable(); to your code. It could be CSRF filter intercepts your request.

I see the filter call in the logs you prvided.